# Get json items from array item inside array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, dom

I have an array of arrays:

```
var json = {
    "music": {
        "albums": [{
            "name": "foo",
                "tracks": [{
                "name": "foo",
                    "ref": "1"
            }, {
                "name": "bar",
                    "ref": "2"
            }, {
                "name": "foobar",
                    "ref": "3"
            }]
        }, {
            "name": "bar",
                "tracks": [{
                "name": "f",
                    "ref": "1"
            }, {
                "name": "oo",
                    "ref": "2"
            }, {
                "name": "bar",
                    "ref": "3"
            }]
        }]
    }
};
```

As you can see, `album` is an array containing two arrays and a `name` property. The arrays within album are called `tracks`, which hold the tracks from the album displayed on the dom.
What I am trying  to do is modify the dom with jquery, like this:

```
var gridListMusic = $('#grid-listMusic');
var gridListMusicList = $('#grid-listMusic ul');

    function createAlbumSection(id) {
        gridListMusic.append('<div>' + id + '</div>');
        gridListMusic.append('<div class="grid-container">' + '<ul>' + '</ul>' + '</div');
        $.each(json.music.albums.tracks, function (index, value) {
            gridListMusicList.append('<li>' + value.name + '</li>');
        });
    }

    function jsonDo(data) {
        $.each(data.music.albums, function (index, value) {
            alert(value.name);
            if (typeof data.music.albums !== 'undefined') {
                createAlbumSection(value.name);
            }
        });
    }
```

This is expected to insert divs and uls into the DOM like this:

```
<div>foo</div>
<div class="grid-container">
  <ul>
    <li>foo</li>
    <li>bar</li>
    <li>foobar</li>
  </ul>
</div>

<div>bar</div>
<div class="grid-container">
  <ul>
    <li>f</li>
    <li>oo</li>
    <li>bar</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

However, I am getting this error in my console as soon as it tries to insert the `tracks` in the `<ul>`:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'albums' of undefined

Comment: `albums` is an array. It does not have a property `tracks`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should rewrite your `createAlbumSection` to accept the list of tracks:

```
function createAlbumSection(id, tracks) {
    var html = '<div>' + id + '</div>' + '<div class="grid-container">' + '<ul>';

    $.each(tracks, function (index, value) {
        html += '<li>' + value.name + '</li>';
    });

    html += '</ul>' + '</div>';

    gridListMusic.append(html);
}
```

Then, send it in with your `jsonDo`:

```
function jsonDo(data) {
    $.each(data.music.albums, function (index, value) {
        alert(value.name);
        if (typeof data.music.albums !== 'undefined') {
            createAlbumSection(value.name, value.tracks);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: This does not insert the `<li>`'s inside the unordered lists.

Comment: You mean the `<ul>` within `.grid-container`?

Comment: Yes. It's only inserting the `<ul>`, not the `<li>`'s

Comment: @SebastianOlsen I've edited my answer, it should insert the `<li>` elements within the `<ul>`.

Comment: Much appreciated. I didn't know this question was a duplicate, I couldn't find it on the search, but then again I didn't know nested was a word. Thank you so much for helping me!

Comment: That's weird, I never unchecked it. Oh well, I checked it again. :)

Answer (score 0):

instead of

```
function createAlbumSection(id) {
        gridListMusic.append('<div>' + id + '</div>');
        gridListMusic.append('<div class="grid-container">' + '<ul>' + '</ul>' + '</div');
        $.each(json.music.albums.tracks, function (index, value) {
            gridListMusicList.append('<li>' + value.name + '</li>');
        });
    }
```

use

```
function createAlbumSection(id) {
        gridListMusic.append('<div>' + id + '</div>');
        gridListMusic.append('<div class="grid-container">' + '<ul>' + '</ul>' + '</div');
        $.each(json.music.albums[0].tracks, function (index, value) {
            gridListMusicList.append('<li>' + value.name + '</li>');
        });
    }
```